# Downloading CMIP6 data for a specific area

Tags: python, download, esgf

By default, the CMIP6 netcdf data downloaded from any of the different ESGF portals cover the entire globe. Is there a way to download CMIP6 for a box (e.g., with bounds 20°W,20°E and 15°S,25°N) encompassing a particular region of the world?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the opendap options available over ESGF. This can be cropped easily on the command line using NCO. An example, for a different region, is below:

```
ncks -d i,260,305 -d j,240,290 http://aims3.llnl.gov/thredds/dodsC/css03_data/CMIP6/CMIP/MOHC/UKESM1-0-LL/historical/r1i1p1f2/Omon/tos/gn/v20190406/tos_Omon_UKESM1-0-LL_historical_r1i1p1f2_gn_185001-194912.nc outfile.nc
```

CMIP6 grids are in no way consistent, so you will need to create a different NCO call (or xarray or whatever you choose to use). If you are working with a lot of different models, this might take some time.

If you already have urls for downloading, you should be able to convert them to opendap urls as follows:

```
ff.replace("fileServer","dodsC")
```

where ff is the url.

Answer (score 0):

As a modification to Robert's anwer, if you don't want to calculate the i and j indices, I think you can specify the lat lon range directly using a decimal point:

```
ncks -d lat,-15.,25. -d lon,340.,20. http://aims3.llnl.gov/thredds/dodsC/css03_data/CMIP6/CMIP/MOHC/UKESM1-0-LL/historical/r1i1p1f2/Omon/tos/gn/v20190406/tos_Omon_UKESM1-0-LL_historical_r1i1p1f2_gn_185001-194912.nc outfile.nc
```

Be careful with how you specify the longitude when you have wrapped coordinates across lon=0, [as specified in this answer to Robert's own question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65370084/how-to-crop-a-netcdf-file-by-longitude-in-nco) :-)